# clonezilla works for ssh server but not samba server

Tags: linux, ssh, samba, clonezilla

currently using clonezilla live and i can successfully backup and restore an entire image using the ssh server option.
i specify my user name and also my password and saves the image on my ssh server, venus

however, i repeat the same steps for image, i get the error /home/partimag/ is not a mounting point

I am trying to figure out if my samba server is installed right, or if it is just something going on with my clonezilla?

any advice where to look or research?

Comment: You need to mount it using, I think, `smb://server/share`???

Comment: when i go to the cmd option and mount it, how do i get out of it to go back to the options